# Why does the incrementor at the end of this While statement not fire

Tags: python

I would like to nest a for statement inside of a while loop.  However, in the following example variable d does not increment by one day after the completion of the for statement.  I determined this by printing d out to my screen.

```
while d <= end:
    for row in reader:
        rowDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y")
        if row[1] == offer and rowDate == d:
            rowList.append("1")
    d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

When I indent the incrementor as follows, it does execute.  But this is not the desired result as I do not want it to increment upon each iteration of the for statement.

```
while d <= end:
    for row in reader:
        rowDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y")
        if row[1] == offer and rowDate == d:
            rowList.append("1")
        d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

There's probably something fundamental to Python that I'm failing to grasp.  Can someone please explain why d increments in the second example but not in the first?

Comment: If the while loop only runs once, that would suggest `d == end`...

Comment: Does `reader` have any rows?  How does rowList and rowDate look at the end of each?

Comment: print right after the increment (in the loop). what do you see? :)

Comment: @Interrobang I verified that the starting value of d is less than the end value

Comment: If the `reader` is a `csv.reader` or something similar, you can iterate over it only once. You need to re-instantiate it for every iteration in the `while` loop.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand The reader has many rows.  They print fine in the second example when I nest the incrementor deeper.

Comment: @Avaris The reader is indeed a csv.reader.  But I'm already reinstantiating it and there are no issues with it in the second example.

Comment: @hughesdan: Where are you doing it? I don't see it in any of your examples.

Comment: you are very stubborn. `print d; d += datetime.timedelta(days=1); print d`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Hmmm, printing d immediately following the last line shows what I was expecting (an incrementing date).  However, if I print d right before the if statement, I get the original starting value repeated over and over.

Comment: okay, you made the first step the trace the problem. now keep going.

Comment: Where are you printing out d at? If you are printing out d inside of the for loop, then of course it will be the same. The iterator will be totally used up after the time through the while loop so you would never see that d had actually been incremented after the for loop.

Comment: @JustinPeel Yes that makes sense.  I'm beginning to think that I've been obsessing over a non problem and that the issue may lie elsewhere in my code (e.g. something unrelated to my post).

Comment: If this question is no longer relevant, please delete it.

Answer (score 2):

`csv.reader` returns a generator. Once you go over it, it is consumed. You can't iterate over it twice without re-instantiating it. That's because generally you don't need to go over it more than once. You can rewrite your code like this:

```
for row in reader:
    rowDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%m/%d/%Y")
    if row[1] == offer and start_date<=rowDate<=end_date:
        # start_date and end_date are datetime objects
        rowList.append("1")
```